# How can I use line-break as separator in group_concat function MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I use line-break (`CHAR(10)`) as the separator of function `GROUP_CONCAT` in mysql?

I 've tried `GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR CHAR(10))` but failed.

Comment: This has been [a known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17832) in MySQL for a while.  Just use `\n`, which means the same thing as `CHAR(10)`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Great to know that, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `'\n'`, like in

```
GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR '\n')
```